# How is the scrolling functionality done in this website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am interested in the way [this site](http://www.webstock.org.nz/) has the speakers scrolling at a certain interval.

I am unsure if this is a jQuery plugin but would be keen to know/understand how this functionality is done.

Comment: I don't see...What do you mean?

Comment: @elclanrs - I am referring to the scrolling component of the speakers on the landing page.

Comment: I wonder if the link has changed, and now no longer demonstrates the scrolling effect described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a container element that is set to the dimensions you want to display. Then set its `overflow` property to `hidden` and give it a child that is much taller. Then use a `setInterval` to animate the offset from the child to the parent:

HTML --

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS --

```
#container {
    position : relative;
    width    : 500px;
    height   : 300px;
    overflow : hidden;
}
#child {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 900px;
}
```

JS --

```
$(function () {
    var $child = $('#child'),
        timer  = setInterval(function () {
            $child.animate({ top : '-=300' }, 500);
        }, 1500);
});
```

### Update

You can then detect if the `#child` element should be animated back to the beginning once its entire height has been shown:

```
$(function () {
    var $child   = $('#child'),
        height   = $child.height(),
        interval = 300,
        current  = 0,
        timer    = setInterval(function () {
            current++;
            if ((current * interval) >= height) {
                current = 0;
                $child.stop().animate({ top : 0 }, 1000);
            } else {
                $child.stop().animate({ top : (current * interval * -1) }, 500);
            }
        }, 1500);
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BH5gK/2/